# Uppercase the initial char of every string in a list

Tags: c#, strings, linq, ienumerable

My problem is that I have a sequence, potentially infinite, of strings. Let's suppose it to be

```
{"Mickey Mouse", "Bugs Bunny", "Winnie the Pooh"}
```

I have to make an exthension-method `Initials` that returns a sequence of their capital letters in uppercase, so in this case, doing:

```
var names = new string [] {"Mickey  Mouse", "Bugs    Bunny", "Winnie  the Pooh"}
foreach (var cl in names . Initials ())
Console.WriteLine(cl);
```

returns, in order, MM, BB, WTP. Note that whitespaces have not to be considered.

After hours of staring at the screen, i managed to write this not so goodlooking code:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Initials(this IEnumerable<string> names)
{
    var res = new List<string>();
    var  listOfArrayOfStrings = names.Select(s => s.Split());
    foreach (var arrayOfStrings in listOfArrayOfStrings)
    {
        string newString = "";
        foreach (var singleString in arrayOfStrings)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(singleString)) //no whitespaces
            {
                var temp =  char.ToUpper(singleString[0]).ToString();       //first upper String
                newString += temp;
            }
        }
        res.Add(newString);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Then, my disliked R# suggested me to do some refacory and then it became the following:

```
var  listOfArrayOfStrings = names.Select(s => s.Split());
            return listOfArrayOfStrings.Select(arrayOfStrings => 
                (from singleString in arrayOfStrings 
                 where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(singleString) 
                 select char.ToUpper(singleString[0]).ToString())
                 .Aggregate("", (current, temp) => current + temp))
                 .ToList();
```

Now, I have two questions about this:

1. Is this, in your opinion, a good way to reach my aim?
2. I will have to do a written test where I'll have to do something like that. How can I "guess" something like that without R#? I mean, I'm still having difficulties understanding all that Linq stuff. Have you got any idea to how I can approach problems like this? Often these test are about managing `IEnumerable`s, so Linq could be very helpful, but I rarely understand the right sequence of Linq queries.

Answer (score 4):

Start by writing a method that returns the initials of a single string.

```
private static string GetInitials(string name)
{
    ???
}
```

You have the right idea, but there are some overloads we can use that will make the code a bit nicer:

```
private static string GetInitials(string name)
{
    var initials = name
        .Split((char[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(w => char.ToUpper(w[0]));
    return new string(initials.ToArray());
}
```

Here we've used the overload of `Split` that won't return empty entries, so we don't have to check for empty entries. We've also used the `string(char[])` constructor instead of building up the string ourselves.

Now `Initials` we be written as

```
return names.Select(GetInitials);
```

---

There's a problem with both versions in that the method will not return if the input sequence is infinite (which you've mentioned is a case you want to handle).

Suppose we have this helper method to create an infinite sequence of a single value

```
private static IEnumerable<T> Repeat<T>(T value)
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return value;
    }
}
```

Then our method should be able to handle this client code:

```
foreach (var cl in Repeat("Mickey Mouse").Initials().Take(5))
{
    Console.WriteLine(cl);
}
```

The versions posted must process every element of the sequence before they return, which isn't possible for infinite sequences.

Comment: Note that there's a bit of magic going on with `names.Select(GetInitials)` - the compiler is inferring a number of things. This syntax is called a "method group", and is equivalent to `names.Select(x => GetInitials(x))`. ReSharper makes a suggestion here, to "convert to method group", because the parameter-passing can be inferred since the method only takes a single parameter, `x`. Don't blindly apply R# suggestions - use R# suggestions to learn *when* and *why* such or such formulation is applicable, and only apply suggestions you're comfortable with and that improve readability.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> var names = new string [] {"Mickey  Mouse", "Bugs    Bunny", "Winnie  the Pooh"}
> foreach (var cl in names . Initials ())
> Console.WriteLine(cl);
> ```

Wow this is an utterly confusing way of writing code. Compare to the equivalent:

```
var names = new string [] {"Mickey  Mouse", "Bugs    Bunny", "Winnie  the Pooh"}
foreach (var cl in names.Initials())
{
    Console.WriteLine(cl);
}
```

What are the differences?

- Proper scope-delimiting braces - a `foreach` block defines a scope; using curly braces makes that a lot more apparent.
- Removed extraneous whitespace - dot-notation (`object.Method()`) is a LOT easier to read when there's no whitespace before/after the dot.

Your specifications aren't clear at all:

> *return a sequence of their capital letters in uppercase*

Capital letters *are* usually, well, uppercase. And `"Winnie the Pooh"` doesn't have a capital "T" but your method returns "WTP" for it. I think you have simply misphrased what the function does; if the `Initials` method had XML comments, the description you gave would be completely misleading, **assuming the function does what it's supposed to be doing**.

---

> ```
> var  listOfArrayOfStrings = names.Select(s => s.Split());
> ```

Consider naming variables after their *meaning* rather than their *type* - here you made a relatively confusing mistake: the result of a `Select` call can never be a `List`, so that *list of arrays of strings* is actually not a *list*.

---

ReSharper *suggestions* aren't *recommendations* - they're **suggestions**, and that doesn't mean you have to implement them... especially when readability is taking a beating, as is the case here.

Comment: Some clarifications:
Regarding the  whitespace-dot-notation it has been a mistake due to tiredness because i took the text from a pdf and pasting it on here i didn't remember to fix the whitespaces. 
When there's a foreach, if ecc and it concerns only one line of code, i usually remove the braces because teacher always tell me to remove "useless" braces.

The method has to make the first letter of each word uppercase, even if it isn't a proper name. I used that names but i could have used "lemon tree", " broken wings" and other stuff and what i aspect this method to return is "LT","BW"ecc.

Comment: @Sanci If you remember Apple's 'goto fail' fiasco last year (and if you don't, do a quick search), use that as an example to remind your teacher of why braces are not 'useless' in this case. Readability is VERY important in production code!

Comment: @Sanci even without the braces, the line belongs in another scope and should *at least* be indented to reflect that. Having it unbraced and at the same level of indentation as everything else is asking for maintenance bugs to happen. And I don't agree with your teacher, braces are only useless when they define a scope that doesn't need to exist. When the scope is dictated by language keywords, braces make everything clear and unambiguous.